# String Matching and get more than 1 column in Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, string-matching

I need to match `Name` from df1 to `Item_Name` from df2. Wherever the name matches I also need `Item_Id` and `Material_Name` from df2.

I have two data frames:

Df1:

Original df has 1000+ Name

```
   Id    Name
    1     Paper
    2     Paper Bag
    3     Scissors
    4     Mat
    5     Cat
    6     Good Cat
```

2nd Df:

Original df has 1000+ Item_Name

```
Item_ID   Item_Name    Material_Name
1         Paper Bag      Office
2         wallpaper      Decor
3         paper          Office
4         cat cage       Animal Misc
5         good cat       Animal
```

Expected Output:

```
Id Name              Item_ID      Material_Name
1  Paper              1,2,3       Office,Decor,Office 
2  Paper Bag          1,2,3       Office,Decor,Office 
3  Scissors            NA         NA 
4  Mat                 NA         NA  
5  Cat                4,5         Animal Misc, Animal
6  Good Cat           4,5         Animal Misc,Animal
```

**Code:**

```
def matcher(query):

    matches = [i['Item_ID'] for i in df2[['Item_ID','Name']].to_dict('records') if any(q in i['Name'].lower() for q in query.lower().split())]
    if matches:
        return ','.join(map(str, matches))
    else:
        return 'NA'

df1['Item_ID'] = df1['Name'].apply(matcher)
```

This worked properly when I need to have one column and currently I am running this code twice to get `Item_ID` and `Material_Name`.

**ASK:**

Need help if there is another way to **not to run the function twice** but I can get even 2 or 3 columns in one go

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's hard to interpret your expected output

Comment: Also, `df2[['Item_ID','Name']]` did you mean `df2[['Item_ID','Item_Name']]`?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: That still doesn't make sense with your expected output. For e.g. why is Paper Bag matched with df2's item 1, 2, 3?

Comment: The current code matches both way..that is how I want..if any one word of the compound word matches..then its a match!! So their is no problem in matching, the only problem I get is how to get two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and reusing Boolean masks:

```
def matcher(x):

    # construct 2-way mask
    m1 = df2['Item_Name'].str.contains(x, regex=False, case=False)
    m2 = [any(w in i.lower() for w in x.lower().split()) for i in df2['Item_Name']]

    # apply 2-way mask
    res_id = df2.loc[m1 | m2, 'Item_ID']
    res_mat = df2.loc[m1 | m2, 'Material_Name']

    return ','.join(res_id.astype(str)), ','.join(res_mat.astype(str))

df1[['Item_ID', 'Material_Name']] = pd.DataFrame(df1['Name'].apply(matcher).tolist())

print(df1)

   Id       Name Item_ID        Material_Name
0   1      Paper   1,2,3  Office,Decor,Office
1   2  Paper Bag   1,2,3  Office,Decor,Office
2   3   Scissors                             
3   4        Mat                             
4   5        Cat     4,5   Animal Misc,Animal
5   6   Good Cat     4,5   Animal Misc,Animal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting both `Item_ID` and `Material_Name` as a tuple from your query, then apply the appropriate column with `[i[0] for i in matches]` or `[i[1] for i in matches]`.

```
def matcher(query):
    matches = [(i['Item_ID'], i['Material_Name']) for i in df2[['Item_ID','Name']].to_dict('records') if any(q in i['Name'].lower() for q in df1['Name'].lower().split())]

    if matches:
        df1['Material_Name'].apply(','.join(map(str, [i[1] for i in matches])))
        return ','.join(map(str, [i[0] for i in matches]))
    else:
        df1['Material_Name'].apply("NA")
        return 'NA'

df1['Item_ID'] = df1['Name'].apply(matcher)
```

Comment: Sry I'm not able to test this code till later, but let me know how it goes

Comment: Can't we use `map` function here somehow to get it in one line

Comment: Also, we are just passing Item_Id, how can I get two column names in the expected output